# How to recover bricked installation due to "netsh rpc add x.x.x.x" cmd?

Tags: windows, security

I broke my windows 2008 r2 installation by running `netsh rpc add x.x.x.x` where `x.x.x.x` is my LANs subnet.

Using <kbd>F8</kbd>  to boot in `Safe Mode` and `Last Known Good Configuration` either blue screens or hangs with a black screen.

I can dual boot into a working Windows installation.

How can I undo the `netsh` command to recover the install?

Comment: first, a point of terminology, your machine is not bricked. a bricked device will never ever work again without the replacement of hardware components. second, if the machine won't boot, you can't use netsh to do anything with it. you will have to repair the installation, perhaps using a boot cd and windows restore options.

Comment: What blue screen code is it?

Comment: Solution:

1. Load the registry hive for the broken installation
2. Delete the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSetXX\services\Rpc\Linkage key